# When do angular momenta decouple again?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

If we have two angular momenta, $j_1$ and $j_2$, which couple to the total angular momentum $J$, we can choose between two sets of basis systems,
$$ (j_1,m_1,j_2,m_2)\;\text{ vs. }\;(j_1,j_2,J,M). $$
The second one is useful, because $J$ being the total angular momentum of the system corresponds to a conserved quantity and plays the role of the generator of rotations.

This leads to my question: when is it useful to instead consider the first basis set, i.e. when is it useful to consider *decoupled* angular momenta?

*(I know one example is the Paschen–Back effect, but are there other cases as well..?)*

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we have multiple basis it’s generally a good idea to look at the energy scales of different parts of the Hamiltonian. For example, consider the hydrogen atom Hamiltonian with the spin-orbit coupling: $$H=H_{coul} + H_{SO}$$ where $H_{coul}$ is the coulomb term and $H_{SO}$ is the spin-orbit coupling term. The energy scale of the coulomb term is of the order of $10$ eV and that of the spin-orbit coupling is of the order of $10^{-5}$ eV. What this means is that we can treat the spin-orbit as a perturbation to the coulomb term. So in this case, as the coulomb term commutes with individual z-component of angular momentum operators the $j_1,m_1;j_2,m_2$ basis is easier to work with.

With multielectron systems a third term comes into picture. The electron-electron correlation. And this term doesn’t commute with the individual $L_z$. So for these systems, if the correlation energy is much lower than spin-orbit (both are generally much lower than coulomb), then we can use the decoupled basis generally known as $ls$ basis. This is heavily used in spectroscopy, known as [Russel-Saunders coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol). On the other hand if the correlation energy is higher than the spin-orbit coupling (as is the case in some actinides) we use the coupled basis generally known as $jj$ basis.